# Tricky integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, fresnel-integrals

I am trying to do the following integral for a few days now, but getting nowhere.

\begin{align}
\int_0^x \mathrm dy\,y^2 \cos(y^2) C^2 \!\!\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\,y}{\sqrt\pi}\!\right)\!
\end{align}

In reality only the first one is causing me troubles, however I have pasted the entire expression as it might lead to some cancellations. Any help would be welcome. $C()$ is the Fresnel integral.

Comment: No, it is Sqrt(4)=2 there.

Comment: For the record, I have tried numerous approaches with integration by parts, all of the fruitless.

Comment: Please specify the argument convention for the Fresnel integral. This is the same as Mathematica uses, am I correct? So, in traditional form we can write $2/\pi C^2(y)=2/\pi (\int_0^y \cos (t^2) dt )^2$ instead